# How to set up Serenity properties to run tests on mobile device on browserstack

Tags: serenity-bdd, browserstack

I am investigating running serenity + JBehave tests on browserstack. I set capabilities in serenity.properties file:

```
browserstack.user=...
browserstack.key=...
browserstack.server=hub-cloud.browserstack.com

browserstack.browserName=iPhone
browserstack.device=iPhone 8 Plus
browserstack.realMobile=true
browserstack.os_version=11
browserstack.name=Bstack-[Java] Sample Test

webdriver.driver=remote
webdriver.remote.url=https://myUser:myKey@hubcloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub
```

I run test. They are executed on browserstack, but always on Windows. My mobile device settings are completely ignored. I generated settings on browserstack page.

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

My test is purely based on Serenity and it works fine on BrowserStack when I pass the following for mobile device:

```
browserstack.user=UserName
browserstack.key=Access_Key
browserstack.server=hub-cloud.browserstack.com

environment.single.name=single_test
environment.single.device = iPhone 8 Plus
environment.single.realMobile = true
environment.single.os_version = 11
```

Comment: Thanks Himanshu
I tried with your setting, but tests are run on Windows 10, Firefox 67.
Could you tell me how you set webdriver.driver  property?